# setting an asp variable via java script

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net, client-side

i have an aspx.cs page:

```
public partial class multiIndex : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public string Link = "";
    public string board = "";
    public string against = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

and an aspx page and in it a script and this code:

```
<script>
var newBoard = "<%=board%>";
<%UpdateDataBase(board)%>
</script>
```

now this is working but i can't use it in reverse:

```
var board = "something";
<%board=%>= board;
<%UpdateDataBase(board)%>
```

so how do i do such a thing without php or any other libarary like node.js, i want to keep it simple

Comment: You need to differentiate what are asp pages, what is javascript. You mention php and node.js so i assume you are begginer as you are mixing terms. Asp are pages which are created on server and sent to user, javascript is executed on your browser. You variable doesnt exist when your page is rendered. For deeper understanding you need to know how asp lIfecycle works. For using server sode variables you need to use session or cookie variables, and states can be changed by postback, or via javascript (ajax)

Comment: i have session variable but i can't understand how to change it, can you show me some example code?

Comment: You can acces session object with HttpContext.Current.Session. But you need to do that on server code smth.aspx.cs and not on smth.aspx. You can set that variable with button onclick event, and set value as HttpContext.Current.Session["varName"] = textboxId.Text; Be aware of handling null values

Comment: i don't want to add buttons because i'm making an online card game, i have already done everything  accept passing this variable to update the board, isn't there a way to just request it from the server (asp.cs) and set a java script variable to be equal to it?

Comment: Just do everything with javascript then.

Comment: but i need to get data from a data base, anyway i have solved this issue using cookies but thanks ( :

Comment: Read about ajax call, pretty simple way to get data from server directly to frontend without refreshing website.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting confused with the point of execution (whether Server or Browser) here. ".aspx" page is rendered by Server and it will be able to edit the contents of the page using the logic you have written. So when you have a code like this `var newBoard = "<%=board%>";`, Server evaluates the value of `board` and assigns the constant value to `newBoard` before rendering the page. You can check this using the developer tools in browser.

But if you want to set the value of "newBoard" in "Board" that is not possible in Javascript as it is executed in browser and the variable "Board" has meaning only in Server in the appropriate scope of program execution. If your intention is to do some Server side processing, then you can use API calls to the Server to do the necessary processing.

Answer (score 0):

To set and get asp variables (server side) you just need to create a cookie in the page.aspx.cs page and get it using java script in the page.aspx, because a cookie exists on the server and client any change to it will be registered on the client and server.